# DataGridView column calculation

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I have a column called 'Total' in my datagridview and this column needs to perform a calculation.

I have these columns in the datagridview:

1. 'worked' : a 1 or 2 value (1 means normal time and 2 means over time)
2. 'hoursSpent' : double type value (e.g. 5.40)
3. 'normalTimeRate'  : double type value (e.g. $3.50)
4. 'overTimeRate'    : double type value (e.g. $4.50)
5. 'total' : text

The names in the '...' is their name in the data property name of the column.

The thing is I need 'total' to calculate the (hoursSpent* normalTimeRate or OverTimeRate) (so, if the 'worked' column has a '1' value it would calculate (hoursSpent*normalTimeRate)).

CODE: http://pastebin.com/u1A1sHU1

Comment: Are you using any code to populate the DataGridView? If so, then update your question to show it.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated this question including my code. Hope I get some help cos im stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform the "Total" calculation within the SELECT statement as follows:

```
    sSQL = "SELECT B.laborHours_id, " & _
                "A.labor_id, " & _
                "A.first_name + ' ' + A.last_name as name, " & _
                "B.project_id, " & _
                "B.location_id, " & _
                "B.dates, " & _
                "B.worked, " & _
                "B.hoursSpentOnDay, " & _
                "B.normalTimeRate, " & _
                "B.overTimeRate, " & _
                "B.hoursSpentOnDay * IIf(B.worked = 1, B.normalTimeRate, B.overTimeRate) As Total" & _
        "FROM tblLabor A, tblLaborHours B " & _
        "WHERE A.labor_id = B.labor_id "
```

Comment: I forgot and & _ after Total and have amended the string. It is a compilation error wasn't it?

Comment: it worked, but it is only calculating on overTimeRate. It seems like it is ignoring the normalTimeRate...

Comment: Are you certain the normalTimeRate = 1?

Comment: Ok I managed to do it. Thank you so much Sir. I took a look at your website and you seem to be a very talented person. (I updated your answer)

Comment: Thanks for the kind words.